# FB.login callback not called in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have a facebook app that is going to be installed on a facebook page. When an end user visits this app, he'll be asked to authorize the app. I'm using FB.login in JS to authorize and I do get facebook dialog asking for permission. But the control does not come to callback of FB.login at all. What am I missing here?

```
FB.init({
    appId: <app_id>
});
FB.login(function(response){
    console.log(response); //control never comes here even after user authorizing the app
}, {scope:"email,userlikes"});
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a wrong permission here.

Replace `userlikes` with `user_likes`

(I dont think even the permissions were asked with your code since the permission is incorrect)

[Check this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpZK7/). When you close the login dialog, check the console of the browser, you'll see the response.